# How to save data in document directory without replacing previous one

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I am new in swift macos development,
I am using this code but it is used to replace previous one but i want not to replace,
I want to add new and also want to contain previous
thanks in advance

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask)[0] as NSURL
    
 // add a filename
 let fileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("fl10_accounts.xml")
    
 // write to it
 //try! data
 try! data.write(to: fileUrl!, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
 print("File Created")
```

I am trying to add new data and also previously saved data in same named file

Comment: As the file is in XML format you cannot just *add* content. You have to read the entire file, decode it, modify it, encode it and write it back. And don’t use `NSURL` in Swift. There is native `URL`.

Comment: just change the name of file for example "fl10_accounts.xml" if already exist then change the name to "fl10_accounts(1).xml" and so on

Comment: if you are not going to change the name the file will be override to previous file and save

Comment: Zeeshan Ahmed i have xml file named "fl10_accounts.xml". i want to save new data in this file also my previous data in this file should remain

Comment: @vadian help me to find how we can read xml file from document directory

Comment: With `PropertyListSerialization` or `PropertyListDecoder`. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+xml+%5Bswift%5D) are related questions how to parse XML in Swift.

Comment: @vadian i want to read xml file from my document directory
i need help in this

Comment: @vadian Thanks man i got your point and worked for me 
thanks alot again